# How to sum data by Month in LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to present data in different format in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720175/how-to-present-data-in-different-format-in-linq)

I am having data in below format in datatable

**DATA IN TABLE:**

```
 DEVICEID   PRODUCTCODE  MONTH NO      QTY      VENDAMT
----------- ----------- ----------- ------------------- ---- -------
    2032     100            06           9        270
    2032     101            06           4        120
    2032     102            06           1         30
    2032     100            07          10        300
    2032     101            07           8        240
    2032     102            07           9        270
```

I want to show it in following format using LINQ query in C#

```
 DEVICEID    PRODUCTCODE JUN_QTY JUN_AMT JUL_QTY JUL_AMT
----------- ----------- ----------- ------------------- ---- -------
2032          100             9  270       10      300
2032          101             4  120       8       240
2032          102             1  30        9       270
```

I tried with this query :

```
var query2 = from p in tempDt222.AsEnumerable()
             select new {
                 DEVICEID= p.Field<Int32>("DEVICEID"), 
                 PRODUCTCODE = p.Field<String>("PRODUCTCODE"),
                 JAN_QTY = (p.Field<String>("MONTH_NO") == "01" ? p.Field<Int32>("QTY") : 0),
                 JAN_AMT = (p.Field<String>("MONTH_NO") == "01" ? p.Field<Int32>("VENDAMT") : 0),
                 ...
                 DEC_AMT = (p.Field<String>("MONTH_NO") == "12" ? p.Field<Int32>("VENDAMT") : 0)
              };
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a GroupBy on your month no column.

You then will need to write some code to format the output so that month number values in the rows are displayed as textual column headings.